# Ubuntu 18.04, am trying to update ffmpeg from 3.x to 4.x, but keeps saying "ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.2.2-1build1~18.04.sav0)"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Ubuntu 18.04, and am trying to upgrade FFmpeg to 4.x using the instructions [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/). However it keeps saying

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.2.2-1build1~18.04.sav0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
```

Upon running `ffmpeg --version`

```
ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-doc
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
```

I have tried following multiple guides on the web, but no dice. Can anyone help?
I suspect some packages are corrupt/invalid on this server, but no idea how to proceed.
TIA

Comment: It may be because one was installed pre-snap and the new one post-snap. Try removing the old version then follow those instructions to install new version.

Comment: What is the output of `type -a ffmpeg` and `/snap/bin/ffmpeg --version`?

Comment: I uninstalled snap ffmpeg, deleted the old FFmpeg folder and reinstalled apt install FFmpeg and now it seems to work. Thanks very much for your guidance!

Comment: @jpezz pls post your response as an answer so I can accept it. Your suggestion got me on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are differences between installing a package using snap and installing it directly. If you have a pre-snap version and the snap version is newer, then remove the old package and install the snap version

```
sudo apt-get remove package-name
sudo snap install package-name
```

Remember, to update non-snap packages

```
sudo apt-get update package-name
```

but to update a snap package,

```
sudo snap refresh package-name
```